# Change TextBlock foreground for specific letters

Tags: c#

is it possible to change the foreground of a TextBlock for specific letters?
Say for the last three I choose red, instead of the default black.

Can I command this via C#?

Comment: Can you draw a picture of what it is that you want?

Comment: Image the word "Car". I want to have the "C" in black, and "ar" in red.

Comment: Is it always three letters or always the last three?

Comment: No, I want to decide in code how much letters should be in a different color.

Comment: Sounds like you need a custom control. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating your text as a series of `Run`s.

```
    <TextBlock>
        <Run>C</Run>
        <Run Foreground="Red">ar</Run>
    </TextBlock>
```

Or to do it from codebehind:

```
  var textblock = new TextBlock();
  textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("C"));
  textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("ar") {Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)});
```

Comment: For XAML this might be right, but I seek the C# solution for this problem.

Comment: @IMX Why then is the question tagged with XAML?